# Checkboxes are returning "on" instead of the value set

Tags: php, html, forms

I am unable to produce output when I check checkboxes. I am running Ubuntu Linux 18.04.2 with Apache version 2.4.29, MySQL version 5.7.27, and PHP version 7.2.19.

As far as I can tell, I am setting up checkboxes correctly, but they return a value of "on" instead of the numeric value I set on the page. I have included a print_r request to find out what is happening.

input script:

```
    for ($aid = 0; $aid < count($a_id); $aid++)
{
print '<input type="checkbox" NAME="articleid[' . $aid . '] VALUE="' . $a_id[$aid] . '">text<br>
';
}
```

input page source:

```
        <input type="checkbox" NAME="articleid[0] VALUE="1">text<br>
        <input type="checkbox" NAME="articleid[1] VALUE="42">text<br>
```

etc.

output script:

```
   print_r($articleid);
```

output page source with 2 boxes checked:

```
    Array
    (
        [20] => on
        [32] => on
    )
```

For checked checkboxes, I expect a numeric result I can use to locate a record for further processing, but I am merely getting an indication that they are checked. There are no error messages.

Comment: Your `name` attribute values are missing their closing `"`

Comment: Thanks for providing the rendered HTML source (your _"input page source"_ part). Hardly anyone does that when asking PHP / HTML questions

Comment: Hanging my head in shame.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using exactly this line of code

```
<input type="checkbox" NAME="articleid[' . $aid . '] VALUE="' . $a_id[$aid] . '">text<br>
```

then you have error right in here

```
NAME="articleid[' . $aid . '] VALUE="' . $a_id[$aid] . '"
```

it must be

```
name="articleid[' . $aid . ']" value="' . $a_id[$aid] . '"
```

you just forget a simple **"** before *value*

In conclusion

```
for ($aid = 0; $aid < count($a_id); $aid++)
  {
    print '<input type="checkbox" name="articleid[' . $aid . ']" value="' . $a_id[$aid] . '">text<br>';
  }
```

Also I think its better to write html attributes in lowercase.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't know how many times I looked and did not see that mistake.

Comment: To prevent these kind of mistakes and also cleaner and more structured coding, it is better to use a form builder library that you don't have to write form elements all by your self.